# Visual Studio (.net) alternative for simple programs

Tags: .net, visual-studio, porting

My apologies in advance if asked before but my searches were not fruitful.

What I want to ask is if there is an alternative for .NET or an inline solution for simple programs. I mean assuming that I am developing a very simple app in "Hello World!" standards, asking user to have entire .NET framework is a bit illogical.

I noticed VC redists but they are for C++ and limited libraries I believe.

So what is the best way for achieving this preferably by C# or VB or something RAD?

Thanks.

Comment: By "entire .NET framework" did you mean Visual Studio? Or did you really mean the .NET Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Small Basic.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/ff384126.aspx

Stripped down version of VB, simple and easy to use. Built basically for 6th graders.

Or

You may just want to try C++'s MFC. Basically just straight C++ minus the .net part. With UI capabilities.

Comment: And yet, still a download and requires a redistributable in order to run on any other machine.

Comment: It does not run off the .Net framework?

Comment: Exactly. The OP is asking for _alternatives_ to .NET.

Comment: Seems requiring 3.5 SP1. I missed VB6, btw.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript or VBScript - the [windows scripting host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) supports both languages and has been part of Windows since at least XP.

Comment: VB Script is a good solution, depending on the complexity of what he needs. He may just want to go with batch files.

Comment: @tcables - I considered that, but rejected batch files as too limited, in particular when WSH is already on most computers.

Comment: Well, just because I said "Hello World!" standards, don't limit yourself :) It may include other things like database connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I also like http://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 0):

SharpDevelop is free and lightweight - get it [here](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/).  Below is an example project I am working on (using NUnit testing framework).

[image: SharpDevelop]